# In lualatex, hyphenation doesn't seem to work for words that contain certain ligatures

Tags: luatex, fontspec, hyphenation, ligatures

It would seem that hyphenation does not work properly under `LuaLaTeX` if the hyphenation points occur at places where TeX inserts ligatures. Consider the following MWE, which (i) provides hyphenation points for seven selected words and (ii) prints them using a very narrow measure (in order to force TeX to use all possible hyphenation points):

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=4.2in]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\hyphenation{white-space Keynes-ian dwarf-ish calf-like wolf-fish ruff-like roof-top}
\begin{document} 
whitespace Keynesian dwarfish calflike wolffish rufflike rooftop 
\end{document}
```

I chose the font "EB Garamond" because it provides the `ft` ligature as well as the "standard five" f-ligatures (`ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl`). The output of the MWE looks like this:

[image]

Observe that the first two words in the list, `whitespace` and `Keynesian`, are hyphenated correctly. In case you're curious: without help from the `\hyphenation` command, TeX would hyphenate these two words as `whites-pace` and `Key-ne-sian`. Yikes!

However, the five other words are *not hyphenated at all* despite the fact that explicit hyphenation points are supplied. [Aside: When run under either `pdflatex` (without loading the `fontspec` package, obviously) or `XeLaTeX`, this MWE runs correctly, i.e.,  the words are hyphenated at the specified hyphenation points.] The thing these words have in common is that they all contain ligatures that cross the specified hyphenation points. This makes me think that `LuaLaTeX` replaces various character pairs (or triples) with ligatures *before* it considers hyphenation possibilities.

What strengthens my belief in the correctness of this diagnosis is that if I use the font  "Latin Modern" (which does not contain the "ft" ligature) instead of "EB Garamond", the word "rooftop" is once again hyphenated correctly, whereas the remaining four words with f-ligatures (i.e., dwarfish, calflike, wolffish, and rufflike) still aren't hyphenated at all. Likewise, when I load the font "Aldus LT Std" -- which only has the "fi" and "fl" ligatures, but no "ff", "ffi", "ffl", or "ft" ligatures -- the word "wolffish" is hyphenated as well, whereas "dwarfish", "calflike", and "rufflike" still aren't hyphenated.

Somewhat surprisingly, I've discovered that if I comment out the instruction `\usepackage{fontspec}`, hyphenation *does* work once again in `LuaLaTeX`. However, if the `fontspec` package is not loaded explicitly, one can't access fonts other than "Computer Modern".

**Questions:** Has LuaLaTeX's hyphenation algorithm changed recently, and/or has `fontspec` changed recently? (Decidedly for the worse, I'm tempted to say...) Alternatively, has the `\hyphenation` command become obsolete? If it's the latter, which command *should* I be using instead to specify hyphenation points?

Comment: When `fontspec` is not loaded, the default font is `cmr10`, not Latin Modern. This seems a bug with OpenType fonts: it fails with *all* ligatures.

Comment: Looks like a `luaotfload` bug when in `node` mode, with `Renderer=Basic` (`base` mode) fontspec option I get the hyphenation correctly.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing out this mistake; I will correct the write-up. Please consider posting your comment as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Thanks for zeroing in on the source of the bug. Please consider posting your comment (possibly with a bit more information on how to select the alternative manner of loading the `luaotfload` package) as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment above, this seems like a bug in `luaotfload` when in `node` mode (the default font rendering mode which does more faithful OpenType processing), switching to `base` mode fixes it (a more limited rendering mode that tries to map OpenType font feature to legacy TeX ligaturing mechanism as far as possible), for example:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=4.2in]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic]{EB Garamond}
\hyphenation{white-space Keynes-ian dwarf-ish calf-like wolf-fish ruff-like roof-top}
\begin{document} 
whitespace Keynesian dwarfish calflike wolffish rufflike rooftop 
\end{document}
```

`Renderer=Basic` tells fontspec to use `base` mode.

This can be a bug inherited from ConTeXt font code that `luaotfload` re-packages for LaTeX and Plain, but not yet confirmed.

If you only need basic ligatures (and may be kerning, not sure), then `basic` mode should be enough until this bug is solved.

I opened a `luaotfload` [issue](https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload/issues/43) to keep track of this bug.

Comment: A "status report" of sorts on this issue: Using TeXLive2014/pre, the `Renderer=Basic` option is no longer needed to get hyphenation across potential ligatures *if* `EB Garamond` is in use. However, this may be due more to some improved capabilities of `EB Garamond` than to structural improvements in `luaotfload`. For sure, the `Renderer=Basic` option is still needed if many other fonts -- say, `Latin Modern Roman`, `XITS`, and `Calibri` -- are used. (Of course, `XITS` doesn't feature an `ft` ligature and hence there's no problem with hyphenating "rooftop" for that font.)

Comment: @Mico Yes, and you have to check the output carefully even for EB Garamond: “dwarfish” is hyphenated in the right place, but the dot on the i disappears from the PDF (copying and pasting does give “dwarf-ish”).

Comment: @Thérèse - Thanks for pointing out the missing dot on the "i" in [dwarf-]ish. Probably something for Georg Duffner (the author of EB Garamond) to look into.