# Ligature suppression algorithm fails if the word in question contains an Umlaut (dieresis) before the ligature

Tags: luatex, typography, ligatures

This is a follow-up posting prompted by Taco Hoekwater's recent [excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62814/5001) to a question I posed a few months ago. It concerns the use of the ligature suppression algorithm for words (mainly, but not exclusively, German-language words) that contain *Umlaute* (diereses).

Taking Taco's MWE as the starting point (not reproduced below because it's quite long), add the instructions

```
\suppressligature{lffach}{lf|fach} %% no f-ligature in words containing the string "lffach"
\suppressligature{rflich}{rf|lich} %% ditto for words containing the string "rflich"
\suppressligature{mpfflug}{mpf|flug}
```

and the following six words (which all contain potential f-ligature glyphs):

```
elffach zwölffach                %% ff ligature to be suppressed
verwerflich dörflich             %% fl ligature to be suppressed
Kampfflugzeug Düsenkampfflugzeug %% ffl ligature to be replaced with f-fl
```

after `\begin{document}`. This results in the following output:

[image]

Notice that the three words which do *not* contain an Umlaut before the `|` ligature suppression point are treated correctly, i.e., the `ff`, `fl`, and `ffl` ligatures are broken up in the manner indicated by the applicable `\suppressligature` commands. In contrast, ligature suppression *fails* for the second set of three words -- apparently because they contain an Umlaut. This happens with words containing an `ä` Umlaut as well, by the way.

Furthermore, I've determined that this problem *only* appears to happen with words that contain an Umlaut *before* the ligature suppression point. Words that contain an Umlaut *after* the ligature suppression point indicated by a corresponding `\suppressligature` instruction are treated correctly. E.g., when supplying the instruction `\suppressligature{uflös}{uf|lös}`, the words `auflösen` and `Auflösung` are both rendered without the `fl` ligature.

A word about my TeX setup: I mostly run TeXLive2011 and use TeXWorks as my editor program. However, the problem also occurs under MiKTeX2.9, with all the latest updates installed, and with WinEdt7.0 as the editor. Both editors are fully unicode-aware.

**Question**: How does Taco's code need to be edited/modified to circumvent the problem(s) described in this posting?

Comment: I don't have a fix, but I assume this is due to the fact that `string.find()`  (and `unicode.utf8.find()`) return the number of bytes, not chars. The debug message `Position n` is off by one in 'Zwölffach'.

Comment: even though you're apparently using unicode (utf8?) input, this looks suspiciously similar to the reasoning by which it's decided whether or not hyphenation is applied.  what happens if you feed those same words into `\showhyphens`?

Comment: You can easily check this if you compare `elffach` and `ölffach` with debug messages. They have the same amount of letters before/after the ligature and yet give different results on the console.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- With Taco's new code, hyphenation issues are now separate from non-ligation issues. I.e., hyphenation *can* but does not *have to* happen at the points where ligatures are suppressed. Considering specifically some German language words and using the `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instruction to load German-language hyphenation patterns, I've discovered that there's a hyphenation mistake, e.g., in the word "Laufindex" (loosely translated as "running index"): TeX identifies the following hyphenation points: Lau-f-in-dex; the  first hyphenation point is an error...

Comment: @PatrickGundlach -- thanks for identifying the source of the error (the potentially inappropriate use of the lua function `string.find`). This also explains the odd rendering of the word `Düsenkampfflugzeug` (instead of `f-fl` one gets `ff-l`). Is there a version of the `string.find` function that's not tripped up by non-ascii characters, or does a solution require a different approach?

Comment: See the message here for a solution to utf8-find: http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2010-March/001262.html

Comment: @Patrick: you should convert one of your comments into an answer. The byte-based return value is exactly the issue.

Comment: @TacoHoekwater the analysis might be correct, but I have no code to show and thus no answer for Mico.

Comment: @TacoHoekwater -- please provide an answer with corrected/updated code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Patrick: I thought you would be able to do this, of all people :) -- answer will follow

Comment: @TacoHoekwater I am so busy these days... thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `string.find` returns a byte location, and in this case you want to have a character index when comparing nodes to strings. The solution is to replace

```
table.insert(throwliga,{match,n,k})
```

with

```
table.insert(throwliga,{prefix_length(f,match),n,k})
```

where `prefix_length` is defined like this:

```
  local prefix_length = function(word,byte)
      return unicode.utf8.len(string.sub(word,0,byte))
  end
```

Which simply returns the length in characters of the prefix of `word` that ends at `byte`.

**Note:** This change only fixes the current problem, it does not solve cases where there are unicode characters inside the strings in the `noliga` table. Please do not ask me to write that as well, there should be some challenge left ;)

Comment: Many thanks for providing this solution! Much appreciated!

Comment: Taco: I've finally posted a complete first version to GitHub of the package "selnolig", which provides ligature suppression methods based on the code you so kindly provided, for both German and English language documents. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2884/5001 for more details and a link to the GitHub repository. Comments very welcome! In the package's user guide I list a few lingering bugs, probably caused by particulars of the lua code. I'm entertaining some hope that you may be able to take a look at them and come up with bug fixes. :-)